# automated login webpage with credentials and browse to different subpage and download that subpage perl or python

Tags: python, perl, html, webautomation

I need help with to Login to webpage using id and password and goto a link within the website and download the complete page code or response that we can see in page source as response for the link. I tried using perl or python but no luck.
I need help with to login to www.server.com:7180 and save cookies and then redirect to ww.server.com:7180/healthissues page or directly download whatever we get response in browser in text file.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import webbrowser
import cookielib
data1={
'j_username':'id', 'j_password':'pass'
}

data = urllib.urlencode(data1)
url = 'http://server.intranet.com:7180/cmf/allHealthIssues'
full_url = url + '?' + data
response = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)
with open("results.html", "w") as f:
f.write(response.read())

webbrowser.open("results.html")
```

The above code downloads the webpage but i always end up with authentication page in the download. I found lot of packages but unfortunately i donot have access to install packages or libraries. Any help is appreciated.

---

I tried with the code suggested by PM 2Ring but I'm getting the error below. I have python 2.6.6 and I'm not sure if that method will work. Please let me know any workaround or way to resolve the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 15, in <module>
    handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Invalid request
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you are importing cookielib you aren't actually using it, so you can't get past the authentication page of the website. The Python docs for [cookielib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#examples) have some simple examples of how to use it. Eg,

```
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://example.com/")
```

Obviously, your code will need to be a little more complicated, as you need to send the password.

So you'll need to do something like this (untested):

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

data1={'j_username':'id', 'j_password':'pass'}
data = urllib.urlencode(data1)  
headers = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'}

req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

It's a shame you can't install Requests, as it makes things *so* much simpler than using the native Python modules.

Comment: I tried with the above as suggested but getting error as below.

Comment: @user3754136: Please don't post error messages as answers; you can edit them into your question (in a quote block or code block). Obviously, I can't test the code without a proper ID and password. But I can't open the `http://server.intranet.com:7180/cmf/allHealthIssues` URL, or `http://server.intranet.com:7180`, either in a browser or from a script.

Comment: That is some dummy link, sorry i work for a bank and the server has production data so cant really share link or login details. But would appreciate any help as to understand the error.

Comment: The code I posted was derived from a script I used to use regularly to login to a forum. It ought to work if you pass **all** the input fields present in the page's login form in the data1 `dict`. That includes hidden fields. And it may even include mouse coordinates on the Submit button. You can discover the required fields by logging in with a browser while using the browser's Live HTTP Headers facilities (you may need to install a browser extension to enable those facilities).

Comment: Can i get thoese fields if i view teh page source of teh login page. I can see something related to Jasascrpt etc..

Comment: @user3754136: Probably, but as I said above it may involve tricky stuff like mouse coordinates on the Submit button, so it's simpler to look at the HTTP Headers. But since this page belongs to the bank you work for, why not just ask someone in the relevant department for the required fields? PS. **Please** delete your answer!

Comment: i need some help on as how does the page gets submitted, as in www-mechanize module the code: mech-> click ('submit'), did the trick of clicking on the login button, but how can we achive this in the above code. Usually in a web page with javascript what should i do so that i can achive the goal of login button click. any help or example how to do that.